# Add a summary to the pdf writer

Tags: table-of-contents, texlive, ubuntu

In some of the books that I have read, in any pdf viewer, there is some kind of tab where i can see the summary of the document, and I can jump to any part (chapter/section) of the document by just clicking on the title on that summary tab.

Well, I can generate a table of contents with `texlive` With the command `\tableofcontents`, but this summary is not really linked to the document, and there is no tab showing in the pdf viewer where i can see the summary and jump to parts (chapters/sections). It looks like the summary I am generating with the command `\tableofcontents` is just some formated text.

My question is : how can I generate a summary which is linked to the document, and which helps to browse the document in a better way.

I am sorry if my question isn't well explained (I really can't find the right words to explain what I need). And for information, I am using texlive under Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: You're probably looking for `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: Isn't your demand related to the pdf-reader that you are using ?

Comment: @wrtlprnft bro, you are just awesome, it did exactly what I wanted. Please put your answer so I can accept it as the correct one please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you're looking for is [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Just loading it has the effect of turning all internal references (in the table of contents, using `\ref`, `\cite` and so on) into clickable links. It also turns your table of contents into *bookmarks*, which are the feature you're looking for. It also provides (or modifies) the `\url` command which can produce clickable links to external resources.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \section{first section}
    \subsection{first subsection}
    \section{second section}
\end{document}
```

It may be worth noting that `hyperref` wants to be loaded as late as possible (i.e. after other packages) because it relies on redefining LaTeX commands that other packages might mess with.